# Maximum visible string length to display in UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, tableview, chat

I'm trying to make a chat using Swift.

I'm using **tableView** with 2 custom rows.
There is a **label** in each of row.

I'm trying to understand the logic chain I must resolve to make this row size depended on label content. So, here it is:

1) Get maximum visible string length for this screen and also this string height.

2) Divide message length to found result. That will be lines count.

3) Set row height = string height * lines count + up and bottom paddings.

4) Set label height like row just without paddings.

The problem is to get results for 1 step. I dont even understand how can I do this. Help me please with that, also any advices about how to make it easier are welcomed :)